# Directory on an NTFS drive suddenly became hidden and doesn't list but it exist

Tags: directory, ntfs

An NTFS drive is mounted which i use as storage, i was copying some files to some of the directories in the drive and before i realised one of the directory named Java went hiding ( it doesn't appear with `ls` command).

here are the ouput of some commands:

```
    $ ls

    Android      CSS            MyStudio  React            Typescript
    Angular      DataStructure  Nodejs    Shell
    ApacheKafka  dwm            Projects  SpringFramework
    AWS          HTMLandCSS     Python    TensorFlow



    $ ls -ld Java

    drwxr-xr-x 1 charlie charlie 24K May 27 20:42 Java



    $ cd ./Java  /* i can cd into it */
    $ cd ../    /* i can cd out of it */



    $ stat Java

    File: Java
    Size: 24576           Blocks: 48         IO Block: 4096   directory
    Device: 8,2     Inode: 30680       Links: 1
    Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/ charlie)   Gid: ( 1000/ charlie)
    Access: 2022-03-20 05:02:07.297922600 +0530
    Modify: 2022-05-27 20:42:30.158342500 +0530
    Change: 2022-05-27 22:29:43.601792800 +0530
    Birth: 2020-02-27 01:18:09.167503000 +0530


    $ mount | grep ntfs

    /dev/sda2 on /home/storage type ntfs3 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,uid
=1000,gid=1000,fmask=37777600033,dmask=37777600022,iocharset=utf8,
discard,prealloc,user)
```

It also doesn't show up in file manager ( ranger ).

Comment: Could be a bug in ntfs-3g, try unmounting and mounting it back again. Also please give NTFS3 a try but *make sure your data is backed up*.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov i am actually using NTFS3

Comment: Umount and mount back again.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov That's been done as well, this problem is from yesterday and i have done a couple of reboot since then, and yet the this particular issue is still there. Very strange behaviour

Comment: Could be a corruption, ntfs3 still has some rough edges. Reboot into windows and run `chkdsk /f Drive:`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov  ```chkdsk /f``` fixed it. i suspect ```ntfsfix``` from linux itself could have done that but i am not sure

Comment: `ntfsfix` in most cases is 100% useless. The `fsck.ntfs` has not been written yet. Paragon claims they have it but they have yet to release it.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov is not available even in the premium version ?

Comment: Could be, I've never purchased it. Edit: indeed, it's available: https://www.paragon-software.com/us/home/ntfs-linux-professional/#features *"chkntfs – check NTFS partition integrity and fix errors"*